# SUM giving incorrect output

Tags: mysql

For my mySQL course, we're creating a database that manages customer orders. One of the questions is asking for me to list all customers and the total revenue per customer.

My issue is that some orders have ordered more than one of the same item, and so when I introduced quantity into the SUM, any order that had multiples of an individual item ordered were summed out incorrectly, but I have no idea how to fix this issue.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
SELECT customers.customer_name, customers.customer_id,
SUM(items.retail_price*orderline.order_qty) AS 'Total Retail Price'
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
INNER JOIN orderline on orders.order_id = orderline.order_id
INNER JOIN items on orderline.item_id = items.item_id
GROUP BY customers.customer_name;
```

I realize it's a bit of a mess as well, so any advice on cleaning it up would be appreciated as well; I've only been working with mySQL for about a month now so its still new to me.

Thanks in advance!

Sample Data:

```
item_id: 300, unit_cost: 156.00, order_qty: 2
item_id: 600, unit_cost:  92.00, order_qty: 2
item_id: 450, unit_cost:  79.98, order_qty: 6
item_id: 600, unit_cost:  92.00, order_qty: 8
item_id: 200, unit_cost: 241.98, order_qty: 4
```

If I did the math right, I'm supposed to get `2,727.80`, but my output for this customer in question is listed as `2,679.80`.

[Link to Code](http://pastebin.com/Kbh72c1A)

Comment: For better clarity can you include some sample data as well?

Comment: This query can't neglect multiple items in same order. Cause you're not grouping on item. Add some sample data to the question.

Comment: I edited the post to include a sample of one of the customers.

Comment: as i calculate sum(unit_cost*order_qty) = 4679.8

Comment: What is `orderline`? Post the data as it is stored in tables, it would be very nice if you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ of it.

Comment: I couldn't get sqlfiddle to work for some reason, so I posted it all to PasteBin and put the link to it at the end of the question.

Comment: The total you showed here `2,727.80` is for which customer? So I can test my results

Comment: It was for Betty Draper

Comment: Well I did the maths too, it should be `2,679.80` for `Betty Draper`. I don't understand how you suppose to get `2,727.80`. Please re-calculate the data you added in the question, my query also gives the same result.

Comment: Welp, that's embarrassing. Yeah, when I calculated everything out prior to the assignment, I failed to write a number down correctly.

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written the query with another logic and here are the results:

**My query:**

```
SELECT c.customer_name, c.customer_id, SUM(o_price.total) as 'Total Retail Price'
    FROM customers c JOIN orders o
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                order_id,
                SUM(i.retail_price * ol.order_qty) as 'total'
            FROM
                orderline ol
            JOIN items i ON ol.item_id = i.item_id
            GROUP BY
                ol.order_id
        ) o_price
    ON o.order_id = o_price.order_id
    GROUP BY c.customer_id
ORDER BY c.customer_id;
```

**My result set:**

```
Cora Blanca     1000    280.80
Yash Reed       1100    1723.88
John Mills      1200    363.24
Tina Evans      1400    4974.32
Will Allen      1500    1444.00
James Boyd      1600    173.58
Ann Damian      1900    271.24
Jane Brown      2100    1213.52
Betty Draper    2200    2679.80
```

**Your result set:**

```
Cora Blanca     1000    280.80
Yash Reed       1100    1723.88
John Mills      1200    363.24
Tina Evans      1400    4974.32
Will Allen      1500    1444.00
James Boyd      1600    173.58
Ann Damian      1900    271.24
Jane Brown      2100    1213.52
Betty Draper    2200    2679.80
```

**Conclusion:**

**Both results are exactly same.** Your query is absolutely fine and well written. And now you have 2 queries for same purpose, apply the best one :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, its nice to know that I had it right, but its also frustrating that I spent as long as I did over an error of my own, haha.

Thanks for also proving that it works with another logic, looking at how you wrote it also helped me understand it better. :)

Comment: Happens sometimes. Remember whenever you get stuck, don't waste too much time. Always discuss with someone, all you need is a fresh perspective to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct c.customer_id, c.customer_name, sum(ol.order_qty * i.retail_price) as total FROM `customers` as c
left join orders as o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
left join orderline as ol ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
left join items as i on i.item_id = ol.item_id
where c.customer_id = 2200
```

The calculation is `2679.80`

Comment: Unfortunately I do need the quantity in order to get an accurate answer as some customers have ordered multiple of the same item. When I don't include the quantity of the item, it simply adds up the total cost of everything as if each person only ordered one of each item, regardless of how many they actually ordered.

The `items` table is also where the unit_price is stored, so I need that as well.